# Obtain the current audio playback stream

Tags: c#, audio, stream

So, I need to obtain the current audio playback that is happening on my pc programatically in real time. This includes all the audio(you can check this in the playback devices tab of the Sound settings). I need it because I'm doing an analysis over the stream which I then put into use in another software. Until now, I've used the 'StereoMix' option, which actually relay's the current audio as an input(something like an internal microphone). However, I can't use this method when I connect external speakers to my pc(through HDMI, PC/AUX works though).

Is there some way to obtain the audio stream no matter if external speakers are connected or not. 
The programming language does not matter in the current case, everything is fine with me. However, I prefer if there is a C# / Processing solution.

EDIT:

Here's the technique(and method) I currently use to obtain the audio in http://code.compartmental.net/minim/minim_method_getlinein.html. The library/code is related to Processing: https://processing.org/.

Comment: The problem is not the stereo mix input, that's correct, the problem is the device, HDMI audio is done through another audio device than the general audio card, i think of you connect the hdmi and default the output device which it uses it should work. Also, add some code to not to guess everything as we don't know nothing about which library you are using and how you retrieve the audio stream.

Comment: @Gusman I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but the moment I plug the HDMI speakers, the StereoMix is not active anymore and it doesn't work. About the code, I haven't pasted anything because I though(and still think) that it won't have any effect on the solution but I'll update my question if this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, NAudio would be a good place to look for a prospective solution.  Its not quite clear what you intend to do with the audio such as if you're recording/dumping data, or simply analyzing live-data so I'm thinking NAudio is going to have something such as you're looking for, as far as getting your hands on live-data.

NAudio has an FFT, but not quite robust in the area of analysis as the JS-libs you may be accustomed to ;)

- http://naudio.codeplex.com/
- https://github.com/naudio/NAudio

There are plenty of examples provided to get you started, and many in the wild.

Though its pretty outdated and the API may or not look slightly different (in regard to...), the following video may provide a nice relaxing quick-start to help familiarize you with this lib.

- [C# Audio Tutorial 6 - Audio Loopback using NAudio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjnTgIdTXwI)

Comment: I am doing a FFT indeed, that's my analysis. I'll look over the library, but in general, do you have any idea if I can still capture the playback audio stream even if it is forwarded through HDMI to a external speakers or TV? Thank you for the input.

Comment: all in all, I'm not quite sure how to answer that—or am not quite clear as to what you mean by 'even if its forwarded...'.  Basically you're dealing with a layer between Windows Native API -> NAudio-interfaces/API (simplification layer).  If you're recording through say, the PC's 'global-mixer', I don't see why whatever output devices you're using would effect the stereo mixer... and I'm not quite sure what behavior you've experienced prior.

Comment: (continued) 

If for example you dis-connect a device (during recording), this will throw off the list of devices (by device-index,  for example, though most have GUID-type-lookups internally).

in other words if constantly plugging or unplugging devices during recording would certainly be messy and throw things off.

but am not seeing a logic breaking a record or stream session from an existing mixer device

Comment: The case is actually pretty simple. I use the StereoMixer as default option for 'Recoding devices'. I then use the minim library(mentioned in the question's edit) as to get the audio input stream and analyze it in realtime. If I use the laptop audio or plug the speakers through the 'pc/aux' port, everything works fine. If I plug the speakers via HDMI to the PC or ChromeCast/YoutubeCast a youtube video to the TV, the StereoMixer is not active anymore.

Comment: interesting.  Okay, think I see now.  So that generally omits coding and/or coding libraries from being (generally) relevant and appearing to be more in the context of system-configuration in which case the particular hardware/vendor of your AudioDevice and operating system play a major role

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to solve such as this, but I would likely find myself tinkering around with device settings and defaults such as setting a 'preferred device', and/or enabling and disabling features of a particular device via Windows mixer settings assuming you're on windows >= 7.
if win >= 7, I would plug in whatever is throwing off the configuration and go into audio-system-management to re-enable the device that was turned off and set it as default perhaps.